# Where do I find my SalesForce WSDLs when I log into SalesForce?

Tags: api, wsdl

I’m trying download/generate WSDLs so that I can generate JAR files for use with my Java application, per the instructions here — https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Introduction_to_the_Force.com_Web_Services_Connector .  The link says “To get your org-specific WSDLs, log into your organization and then click Your Name | Setup | App Setup | Develop | API.”.  However, when I log into SalesForce, under my name there is only “My Profile,” “My Settings,” and “Log Out.”  Where else do I need to look to get my XML-WSDL files?

Comment: Do you see setup next to your name? There are two versions of the setup layout, the older which the article references does have setup under your name - the newer has it as a link next to your name.

Comment: No, there is only "Help & Training" and then a button with the name of our company.

Comment: If you're not a system administrator, you may not have access to Setup.

Answer (score 0):

As @Girbot pointed out, based on what layout you are in it is somewhat similar.  In the new Lightning Experience, you can click on the gear in the upper right hand corner and select Setup Home.  In Salesforce Classic, select setup next to your name in the upper right hand corner.

After both situations above you can then go to the quick find box in the upper right and type "API" where you will see options pop up.

In Lightning it shows: Custom Code --> API
In Classic it shows: Develop --> API

Answer (score 0):

As outlined by @sfdcfox, you are not a system administrator (more specifically do not have the permission "Customize Application") and therefore do not have access to the API option in the setup area. Please see the article [Downloading Salesforce WSDLs and Client Authentication Certificates](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_wsdl.htm&language=en_US) for the permissions needed.

Comment: THis link is only useful if you have the permissions to whcih you refer, right?

Comment: Correct. You need to have your administrator provide you with "Customize Application" OR provide your administrator with the above link so that he/she can download the WSDL for you.